# Nondeterministic finite acceptors basic question

Tags: automata, finite-automata

While studying automata class lecture,
I have a really basic question in nfa.

Q0-a>Q1-lambda>Q2

If graph looks like that,(I can’t post images yet,
FYI Q0-a>Q1 means there is edge (q0,q1) with labeled with a)
Can i say that delta(q0,a)=q2 ?
I think my question is little bit silly but 
I wanna know the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the graph looks like

```
(q0) --a--> (q1) --e--> (q2)
```

Then it is fair to say that

```
delta(q0, a) = (q1)
```

Now, this is not to say that `(q1)` is the only state reachable from `(q0)` by consuming one `a`. Instead, what is typically done is another function `delta*` is defined, maybe from pairs of sets of states and symbols to other sets of states, so that

```
delta*({(q0)}, a) = {(q1), (q2)}
```

If you want to be sure, specify the domain and codomain of `delta` to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your kind answer. But actually  I’m confused about the notations. First, that kind of notation like deleta*({qi},w)= {qk,qj} can be used in nfa? Cause i see that notation only in dfa in my textbook. Second it is obvious that i can use delta*(q0,a)=q2 but , but can i use delta(q0,a)=q1? In my knowledge just delta without * notation cannot be used in this case,but i’m not sure.. thanks agian for your kindness! Have a great day!!

Comment: Oops typo on 7th line. delta(q0,a)=q2

Comment: @Sung-WooHwang A disclaimer - people make mathematics and lots of things are simple conventions. There are multiple equivalent and correct ways of defining NFAs; some might use delta: Q x S -> Q, some might use delta*: 2^Q x S -> 2^Q directly, some might even use Q x S -> 2^Q if they're incorporating the lambda-closure in the right-hand side. Really, for NFAs the function needs to be like delta: Q x S -> 2^Q since multiple transitions can leave the same state on the same symbol. Even then it's OK to say that delta(q0, a) = {(q1)} and distinguish delta*(q0, a) = {(q1),(q2)}.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! 